# Loading local json using dynamic path in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vuejs3

I am trying to do a simple single page website that has texts stored in a local json files. Let's say it is a website that lists famous cartoon cats and dogs each on separate view (page). The view template (views/testcard.vue) for both cats and dogs is the same, but texts for cats and dogs are stored in separate json files (assets/json/cats.json & assets/json/dogs.json).

I know how to import a json to the view, but that is a static path. But the QUESTION IS: How do I import the json to the view using path that is based on props/params so that in case of a cat it is cats.json and in case of a dog it is dogs.json?

The urls are in form of domain.com/cat/garfield I have succesfully made both the specie (cat / dog) and individual animal (Garfield, Pluto...) available in the view file by providing them via router (router/index.js) like shown below.

```
{
        path: "/cats/:currentAnimal",
        name: "Cats",
        component: () => import("../views/Testcard.vue"),
        props: {
            currentType: "cat",
            jsonLocation: "@/assets/json/cats.json",
        },
    },
    {
        path: "/dogs/:currentAnimal",
        name: "Dogs",
        component: () => import("../views/Testcard.vue"),
        props: {
            currentType: "dog",
            jsonLocation: "@/assets/json/dogs.json",
        },
    },
```

And views/Testcard.vue looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <h1>{{ currentAnimal }} is a famous {{ currentType }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
//the line below would work, but it is static path
//import json from '@/assets/json/cats.json';
export default {
    name: "Testcard",
    props: ["currentType", "jsonLocation"],
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();
        const currentAnimal = computed(() => route.params.currentAnimal);
        return {
            currentAnimal,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

I am using Vue3, but this might not be any different from Vue2. The website will not have any calls to outside sources so I would like to keep this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store the `@` alias in the json, or Webpack will fail to locate the file.  You can get rid of the whole path:

```js
jsonLocation: "cats.json"
```

```js
jsonLocation: "dogs.json"
```

When you use `import` dynamically it returns a promise which resolves to a module with the json in the `default` property:

```js
setup(props) {
  import(`@/assets/json/${props.jsonLocation}`).then(module => {
    console.log(module.default);
  });
},
```

Comment: for some reason, I keep getting this `App.vue?847a:20 Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/config/env.local.json'` error, with the same code and correct path